# How to make a legend for all bars in matplotlib barplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make a legend for all bars in my barplot. I have already extracted the labels for all bars, but somehow legend()z only creates a line for the first one and not the second one.

How should I proceed? I was thinking that I maybe have to extract the colors of the bars manually as well, but I don't know. I also hoped there should be an easier way.

```
df.Completeness.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
_, labels = plt.xticks()
label_names = list(map(lambda p: p.get_text(), labels))
print(label_names)
plt.legend(label_names)
```

[image]

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a legend? A legend would be used when the labels do not suffice to clarify what the data shows... for example in this graph https://matplotlib.org/_images/legend_guide-4.png but in your case with the ticks on the x axis is ok. Maybe what you want is to add text in the plot: `plt.text(x, y, "text", fontsize=int) `.

Comment: @Hielke Walinga Can you share the sample data?

Comment: @min2bro http://termbin.com/nrnz its tsv.

Answer (score 0):

Set the color by hand and use mpaches

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
df.Completeness.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
complete = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Complete')
partial = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Partial')
plt.legend(handles=[complete, partial])
```

Comment: You are not answering my question. Your remark is totally correct, but it is not what I want. Also, it does not make sense for the `legend()` to only pick the color of the first bar. I basically need some way to extract the colors of all bars, and pass those manually to the `legend()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this dummy example, do you get the layout that you want?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(2)-1,'B':np.random.rand(2)},index=['val1','val2'] )
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', color=['r','b'])
```